# How to get base64 from Body__s field on Salesforce Classic Knowledge

Tags: rest-api, attachment, knowledge, base64

I am trying to get the base64 encoded version of a Salesforce Classive File Upload field type via the Salesforce REST API from one org to another.

However when I query the rest API for the knowledge article type, I am returned an endpoint as the result for the Body__s field, and that endpoint does not return a base64 encoded version of the body either.

If I query the body__s via workbench query or through Dev Console query, I do get the base64 encoded body__s response.

Does the REST API not support querying on the Body__s field of Salesforce Classic Knowledge articles? Why  can I query this through dev console and workbench, but not through REST Explorer or a call to the REST API?

The response I receive is:

```
My_Knowledge_Article_Attachment__Body__s":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/My_Article_Type__kav/XXX1F00000MASKXXXX/My_Knowledge_Article_Attachment__Body__s"}
```

When going to the link provided in the response, we receive the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 19:51:31 GMT Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="MASK"; pin-sha256="MASK"; pin-sha256="MASK"; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/MASK"; Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/MASK" X-Robots-Tag: none Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private Set-Cookie: BrowserId=MASK; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 24-Jun-2021 19:51:31 GMT; Max-Age=31536000 Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=115/10470000 Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: The reference link should be to a stream of that body's data. Some web clients like Workbench will read the stream and convert it into a base64 string for you, thus why you experience different results in different clients. Have you tried consuming the data in that link and reading it as base64?

Comment: @cricketlang Any documentation or recommendations on consuming the data? See the above response we get back from a GET request on the Body__s link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an additional HTTP GET request against the url returned to you in the `My_Knowledge_Article_Attachment__Body__s` field. Based off the headers you posted, this is returning a `.docx` content type, so we will essentially consume the docx as a blob, encode that blob to base64, then get the string value of that encoded blob.

When you go to get the body of this response, use [getBodyAsBlob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm) to read the data as a Blob, then use the [encodingUtil.base64Encode()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) method to encode the Blob to a base64 String. This should end you with a base64 string of the file downloaded from the attachment body field.

Super rough example:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
String      url     = '{attachmentBodyUrl}';

request.setEndpoint(url);
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+ UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setMethod('GET');

Http         fileClient   = new Http();
HttpResponse response     = fileClient.send(request);
Blob         rawResponse  = response.getBodyAsBlob();
String       base64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(rawResponse);
```